# Trying to store data from text file into vector of objects

Tags: c++, oop, object, vector

I am trying to get a few lines from a text file to store into a class, Item, and using vectors. However, when I read from the file into the program, nothing is stored.

Here is my main:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Item.h"

using namespace std;

void readFile(vector<Item>&); 


int main()
{
  vector<Item> items;
  readFile(items);
  int size = items.size();

  for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
         cout << items[index].getName() << endl;
    }
}
```

This is the function in question:

```
void readFile(vector<Item>& vecItems, int lines)
{
    ifstream inventory;
    inventory.open("inventory.txt");
    string itemName;
    int itemDept, itemPrice, itemQuan, itemShort, itemSurplus;
    string line;

    if (inventory.fail())
    {
        cout << "ERROR NO FILE FOUND (inventory.txt)\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    while (inventory >> itemName >> itemDept >> itemPrice >> itemQuan >>   itemShort >> itemSurplus)
    {
        Item temp(itemName, itemDept, itemPrice, itemQuan, itemShort,   itemSurplus);
        vecItems.push_back(temp);
    }
    inventory.close();
}
```

I've tried calling

```
temp.setName(itemName)
etc etc
```

individually but it still does not hold in the vector. Nothing outputs in main and the debugger says size = 0. Any help is appreciated

EDIT: This is the file format

```
vitamins 1 15.99 1105 500 1000
shampoo 2 6.99 298 300 500
```

Comment: How is the file formatted?  It could be that you have a bad read operation.

Comment: I added it into the OP, can't believe I forgot that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you have a bad read.  `item_price` is declared as an `int` but the price in the file is a floating point number.  When you try to read in `item_price` it capture everything up to the `.` and then stops reading.  On the next read operation for `itemQuan` it gets the `.` and fails as `.` is not a valid `int`.  Since the read fails you never enter the while loop body which means you never create any objects.

Change `item_price` to a `float`, `double` or `std::string` to fix this.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that. Thank you Nate, you're the best

Comment: @MLGSalad It normally is the little things.